# Is it true that cities only use resources within 3 tiles from your city, no matter your city borders?

Tags: civilization-5

A friend claimed this and I can neither confirm nor refute it so far. Is this true?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it is not true.

While a city can only *work* a tile within three steps, it will still provide access to a strategic or luxury resource for your empire if the relevant improvement is built upon that tile and the tile is within the city boundary.

Comment: Now I'm confused... How does your answer and Caffeinated Cake's answer combine?

Comment: @Stijin there's a difference between *working* a tile (and getting +Production, +Gold, whatever from it) and getting access to the resource of the tile (Iron, Uranium, Coal, etc.)

Comment: To clarify slightly, your *empire* will gain the benefits, but the city will not. This is important for resources such as Marble that speeds wonders in the city that conttols the tile it is on.

Comment: Is there any point building, say, a farm in your territory but more than 3 tiles from a city then? If not why are you allowed to do it?

Answer (score -1):

It is true, yes. You can confirm this in the civilization wikia:

> To have access to any Resources, especially Strategic and Luxury ones, you need them to be inside your territory. Founding cities near them (1 to 3 tiles away) is the best way to assure that. **Never forget that a city may only work tiles that are at most 3 tiles away from its main city tile**. So, when choosing the spot, try to include as many Resources within 3 tiles of it as you can. Even though your budding city won't include them into its territory yet, it will start growing it later with exactly this in mind.

[Source](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Settling_a_city_%28Civ5%29)